# Present Interstitial Ad every time the View Controller is presented - Swift 4

Tags: swift, admob, interstitial, viewwillappear

I simply want an Interstitial Ad to appear each time a certain View Controller appears. Here's the relevent code (not everything) ...

```
//import ads, set delegate, and declare variable...
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class myVC: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate {

var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
```

Get the ad ready and present it when the View Controller is presented ...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
    let request = GADRequest()
    interstitial.load(request)
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if (interstitial.isReady) {
        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        interstitial = createAd()
    }
}
```

Ensure the ads will be ready for next time ...

```
func createAd() -> GADInterstitial {

    let inter = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")

    inter.load(GADRequest())
    return inter
}
```

So why isn't this working? I can get the ad to show by pressing a button (I obviously alter the code a little to do that), but I want the ad to simply appear with the presentation on the View Controller. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that I noticed with the `interstitial ad` is that it is not ready when `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` is called. Because of this the check on `interstitial.isReady` fails. The `GADInterstitialDelegate` method has called `interstitialDidReceiveAd` that will tell you when the add is ready. You then need to build some logic around monitoring when an ad is ready, and if you are already displaying an ad to the user.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class AdViewController:UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate {

    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

    private var shouldDisplayAd = true

    private var isAdReady:Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if isAdReady && shouldDisplayAd {
                displayAd()
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(#function)
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "/6499/example/interstitial")
        interstitial.delegate = self
        let request = GADRequest()
        interstitial.load(request)
        print(#function, "shouldDisplayAd", self.shouldDisplayAd, "isAdReady", self.isAdReady)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print(#function, "shouldDisplayAd", self.shouldDisplayAd, "isAdReady", self.isAdReady)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print(#function, "shouldDisplayAd", self.shouldDisplayAd, "isAdReady", self.isAdReady)
    }

    @IBAction func adButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(#function, "shouldDisplayAd", self.shouldDisplayAd, "isAdReady", self.isAdReady)
        displayAd()
    }

    private func displayAd() {
        print(#function, "ad ready", interstitial.isReady)
        if (interstitial.isReady) {
            shouldDisplayAd = false
            interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        }
    }

    private func presentViewController() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let myVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "buttonViewController")
        self.present(myVC, animated: true) { [unowned self] in
            self.shouldDisplayAd = true
            print(#function, "shouldDisplayAd", self.shouldDisplayAd, "isAdReady", self.isAdReady)
        }
    }

    func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "/6499/example/interstitial")
        interstitial.delegate = self
        interstitial.load(GADRequest())
        shouldDisplayAd = false
        return interstitial
    }

    /// Tells the delegate an ad request failed.
    func interstitialDidFail(toPresentScreen ad: GADInterstitial) {
        print(#function, "ad ready", interstitial.isReady)
    }

    func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        print(#function, "ad ready", interstitial.isReady)
        isAdReady = true
    }

    //Tells the delegate the interstitial is to be animated off the screen.
    func interstitialWillDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        print("interstitialWillDismissScreen")
    }

    //Tells the delegate the interstitial had been animated off the screen.
    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        print("interstitialDidDismissScreen")
        presentViewController()
        interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
        print(#function, "shouldDisplayAd", shouldDisplayAd, "isAdReady", isAdReady)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. However, I am wondering why `shouldDisplayAd` is set to `false` in the `private func displayAd()`

Comment: In this example, I set it to `false` because we are presenting an `ad` to the user. When that `ad` gets dismissed, a new `ad` will be loaded and `isAdReady` will be `true`. However, you don't want to show an `ad` just based on when it's ready. You would need to determine when it is appropriate to show an `ad` based on your app's requirements.

Comment: @swiftcoder I ran the code in a sample project and do not experience any crash. If you think the answer is incomplete, or otherwise unacceptable, it would probably be better to **not** mark the answer accepted. Don't feel obligated to accept my answer.

Comment: I originally overlooked the fact that I needed to change the Storyboard ID to `buttonViewController` and that's why it crashed. It doesn't crash anymore. But whenever I close the Ad, another Ad automatically reappears, instead of just showing the VC. This results in an endless cycle that does not allow me to see the VC without an Ad. Is that occurring for you? If so, do you know the fix? Either way, your answer should be helpful to others and I will keep it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: I also noticed that when an Ad is closed, the VC animates and appears on top of itself. This occurs right before another Ad appears automatically.

Comment: There is also the problem with trying to set the VC presentation animation to false. The code `self.present(myVC, animated: false) { [unowned self] in` will not prevent the animation like it should. The code isn't flawless, but it is helpful. It should guide people in the right direction.

Comment: I did not run into the problems you described, but I only have a two view controller project to test the concept. Any kind of a cycle would be tied to the logic in some way. I would suggest looking for a more extensive tutorial or blog post on implementing ads in your app and best practices around ads. Your use cases are going to determine the logic around displaying ads, when, where, and how often. Upon reflection, I would actually display the ad from the presented view controller, not the presenter. Intercepting transitions like this feels like it going to encounter issues.